# Flutter WooCommerce Customer, not registering using Dio?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am buidling flutter woocommerce store app for customers. I want to create/register a new customer using Dio() and I am using WordPress Plugin JWT Authentication for WP REST API for authentication. Here if i want to access URL for Customers Its showing following response. URL= "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers"

```
My Custutomer Model file is:

class CustomerModel {
  String email;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String password;
  CustomerModel(
      {required this.email,
      required this.firstName,
      required this.lastName,
      required this.password});
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
    map.addAll({
      'email': email,
      'first_name': firstName,
      'last_name': lastName,
      'password': password,
      'username': email
    });
    return map;
  }
}
```

My API Service Mothod to create customer is:

```
Future<bool> createCustomer(CustomerModel model) async {
    var authToken =
        base64.encode(utf8.encode(Config.key + ':' + Config.sceret));
    print(authToken);
    bool ret = false;
    try {
      print("${Config.url+ Config.customerURL}");
      var response = await Dio().post(Config.url + Config.customerURL,
          data: model.toJson(),
          options: new Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic $authToken',
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'
          }));

      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        ret = true;
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.response?.statusCode == 404) {
        ret = false;
      } else {
        ret = false;
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

I am sharing my source code. Please download and solve.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZFjsjeEqsGHVJXbmye_BB98gcD-bQFAW/view?usp=share_link

Comment: what does `print(response.statusCode)` print

Answer (score 0):

`HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic $authToken'`
Make this `'Bearer $authToken'`

Comment: Not working. Can you please download source code and help me please...

Comment: i ran your code.. and its returning `I/flutter ( 3168): Http status error [401]` 401 means unauthorized, meaning the credentials you specified.. be it the API key is not valid. so either check the API key.. or check the URL that you used. refer to the documentation https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-customer on how to create a customer